# Visio Line Question

Tags: graphics, line, visio

### Visio Line Question

How do you create a long curvy seamless line in Visio.

WHenever I draw a line it seems to have only the ability to connect objects and that is all.

What f I want to draw a loop that starts from one object and then swoops over the top of another object to make a 300 degree arc?

I have tried this with lines drawn end-to-end.  How do I merge the lines together into one seamless line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First activate the Drawing Toolbar (View/Toolbars/Drawing). With the Drawing Tools you can select to draw straight or curved lines. If you use the squiggly line you can draw a flowing line.

Lines in Visio are shapes, and you can group Shapes. Connect the end points of your lines together, select the ones you want to group, the select Shapes/Grouping/Group to create a group of the individual lines.

Keep in mind that once you create a group of Shapes, the PinX and Pinx (location around with the Shape rotates) tends to change.